MOSFET transistor and capacitors problem
I'm having troubles with the exercise in the picture, containing capacitors and MOSFET transistor.

The text of the exercise is this:
In the circuit shown, Vin(t) is a small voltage generator with null average value. The circuit also contains and ideal current generator IA = 1muA, resistors RD = RL = 150kohm and capacitors C1 = 1 pF, C2 = 100 fF and C tending to infinity. It also comprends the following enrichment transistors:
PMOS M1: VTP1 = -1V, Kp1 = 1muA/V^2
PMOS M2: VTP2 = -1V, Kp2 = 10muA/V^2
PMOS M3: VTP3 = -1V, K_p3 = 1muA/V^2
PMOS M5: VTP5 = -1V, Kp5 = 1muA/V^2
NMOS M4: VTP4 = 1V, Kn4 = 1muA/V^2
NMOS M6: VTP6 = 1V, Kn6 = 40muA/V^2
The channel length modulation effect and substrate effect are neglected.
1) Assuming C1 and C2 initially discharge, for 01 and V2 and indicate what values V3 could take at instant t=150 ns.
2) For t=150 ns, assuming V3=1.5 V, calculate the circuit working point, specifying the operating regions of the transistors, the currents in each branch and the voltages in each node.
I've skipped point 1 'cause i don't know where to start but for the second point i've tried to calculate the voltage of the transistors assuming they were all in saturation but i'm stuck.
Can anyone help?

Do you know that M2 and M3 will act just like a current source? Do you know what the voltage looks like on a capacitor when we charge it from a current source?

@G36 i meant i tried to calculate the voltage at the source, gate and drain of the transistors (if that's what you're asking)

And you did not manage to do so? And what is "mu"? A micro "µ"? We use the small letter "u" for µ.

@BlobFish if you show your work and explain exactly where you're stuck, you will have better luck getting a nudge in the right direction :) It sounds like you don't really know where to start though, maybe consider rereading whatever chapter/learning is associated with this exercise.

Notice that Id2 is 10µA and Id3 = 1µA. Thus, after 200ns V1 will be equal to V1 = (10µA/1pF)*200ns = 2V and V3 = (1µA/0.1pF)*200ns = 2V (assuming saturation) and after 150ns V1 = V2 = 1.5V. Next, you need to find for what Vds2 and Vds3 range the MOSFETs are in saturation region.

@InBedded16 i completely skipped the first point due to the fact that i didn't really know what to do. For the second point i assumed V3 to be 1.5V as given in the exercise and short circuited all capacitors so that V1 = V2 = VG5 = VD2 = VD3 = VG4 = 0V. Then i calculated VD1 = VG1 = VG2 = VG3 but without using current mirror so that's where i might be wrong.
